# How can keep my columns static when I reduce my window?

Tags: html, css

i need to put my column with  text static  on the site, because when i reduce my window its move to the left. I do not know where I can be the problem of this, I trying to change of position: but it does not work. thaks everyone :)

https://codepen.io/ta_io/pen/xebQyE

```
<div class="container2">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="cell" style="width: 220px;">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="infos">
        <small>
                                <table>
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td width="45px">
                                            Date
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            November 17, 2019               </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="45px">
                                                Tags
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a>ONE</a>
                                              <a>TWO  </a>
                                              <a>THREE</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>




                                    </tbody></table>
                            </small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div id="text" class="columns">
        <div class="listenelement">
          Duis molestie tincidunt accumsan. Phasellus fringilla est vitae hendrerit volutpat. Curabitur molestie ante sollicitudin vehicula lobortis. Nam interdum elit tortor. Sed luctus vulputate sapien, sed auctor lectus dignissim a. Vivamus fringilla, enim a
          dignissim consequat, leo ligula ullamcorper sapien, et blandit est libero nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't totally understand your question but from what I grasped, you don't want the table columns to collapse on each other, you can use CSS Grid for this matter, look at `.table` rules ( I erased some of your css sry didn't want to read all of that ). you can play around with the values, if you have more questions or if this is not what you wanted you can ask me in the comments.

```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  html {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;

  }


  body {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
  }



  .container2 {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 85%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .table {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 250px 250px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="cell" style="width: 220px;">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="infos">
        <small>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="45px">
                  Date
                </td>
                <td>
                  November 17, 2019    
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="45px">
                  Tags
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a>ONE</a>
                  <a>TWO  </a>
                  <a>THREE</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div id="text" class="columns">
        <div class="listenelement">
          Duis molestie tincidunt accumsan. Phasellus fringilla est vitae hendrerit volutpat. Curabitur molestie ante sollicitudin vehicula lobortis. Nam interdum elit tortor. Sed luctus vulputate sapien, sed auctor lectus dignissim a. Vivamus fringilla, enim a
          dignissim consequat, leo ligula ullamcorper sapien, et blandit est libero nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```